# Function not found [Error 127]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, hook

I wrote a dll containing a hook procedure. I try to call this function, after loading (with success) the dll, but the result is 0, and GetLastError result 127. I'm using visual studio c++, and this is the code:

dll:

```
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK CBTFrenk(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){...}
```

myapp:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    HINSTANCE hdll = LoadLibrary((LPCTSTR) L"C:\\Users\.....DllForHook.dll");
    wprintf(L"%d\n", GetLastError());
    HOOKPROC pfunc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hdll, "CBTFrenk");
    wprintf(L"%d\n", GetLastError());
    HHOOK handleToAHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, pfunc, hdll, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the collaboration.

edit:

```
    00000000 characteristics
    4E515E9D time date stamp Sun Aug 21 21:38:05 2011
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00011005 ?CBTFrenk@@YGJHIJ@Z = @ILT+0(?CBTFrenk@@YGJHIJ@Z)

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        4000 .text
       10000 .textbss
```

This is the result with dumpbin, why is the name of my function is so strange?

Edit:

```
    00000000 characteristics
    4E520C85 time date stamp Mon Aug 22 10:00:05 2011
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 0001107D _CBTFrenk@12 = @ILT+120(_CBTFrenk@12)

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        4000 .text
       10000 .textbss
```

I declared CBTFrenk like extern "C", and calling "_CBTFrenk@12" it's work.

EDIT:

I wrote the dll code with code::block, and using dumpbin I see that the function name exported is "CBTFrenk@12", and if I try to call it, the function result not found. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: After declaring CBTFrenk as extern "C" it must appear in Dll export table without mangling: "CBTFrenk". Something is still wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try dumpbin with DllForHook library to see whether CBTFrenk function exists. Declare CBTFrenk as extern "C" to prevent C++ name mangling.